# How to generate HTML report streams with JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm creating `PDF` reports with `JasperReports` as follows:
`JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint)`

Now I'd also like to generate a `HTML` text stream. How could I achieve this without having to write that generated file to local disc?

I want to send the generated html as email body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `JasperExportManager`, you could use `JRHtmlExporter`. Try something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(yourJasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(baos)); 

exporter.exportReport();
```

After `exportReport` is called, the `ByteArrayOutputStream` will contain your HTML.

Comment: I just noticed the class is nowadays replaced by `HtmlExporter`, anyways it works as described. Thanks!